# How to debug stuck thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, debugging

I have a multi-threaded C process running under Linux. Occasionally, i.e.: few times a month, one of the threads hangs (it does not reach the sleep which is placed at the end of each thread).

How can I debug it? Is there a way to know what part of the code is executing when the thread gets stuck?

Comment: You've just opened up a whole new world for me! I did not know that I could attach gdb to a running process, nor the existence of core dumps. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help. I converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you can kill it with `kill -11` and then look at the [coredump](https://linux-audit.com/understand-and-configure-core-dumps-work-on-linux/). You can also [attach a debugger](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/developer_guide/debugging-running-application) and see what it's currently doing.

You can also add logging to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDB to debug coredumps.

`#~ gdb <source binary> <coredump file>`

In gdb process, call back trace to get the functions trace leads to crash.

`gdb> bt`